I don't understand Java String.intern() Documentation?
I'm confused about Java's String.intern() method documentation. The official documentation states:

Returns a canonical representation for the string object. A pool of
strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object)
method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this
String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String
object is returned.

But when we create a String using new, isn't the string literal already added to the String Pool? For example:
String s1 = new String("Java");  // Creates 2 objects

So when exactly does intern() actually add a new string to the pool? The documentation seems misleading, or am I missing something?

A string created from a literal will automatically be added to the constant pool. But if we have a string that is, for example, provided by user input, then it can be internalized.

"So when exactly does intern() actually add a new string to the pool?" There is no call to intern() in posted code !? new String(string) does not call intern() and the returned String will not be added to the pool.

s1.intern() will always return the existing ref in the string pool. but the docs says that if the string does not exist it's created. I'm asking when this creation is possible ?

example: reading user input (or from file, database, ...) var input = scanner.nextLine(); input = input.intern() or doing certain string manipulation like var text = "some text".substring(5); text = text.intern() (( the documentation does not say "if the string does not exist" -- it says "if the pool already contains a string equal ... Otherwise"  ))

((( in your code you can check that s1 == "Java" is false but s1.intern() == "Java" is true, since s1 is a new instance, while the literal is already interned  )))

Also when I actually test your code, I do not get the same object as the literal String s1 = new String("Java"); does NOT return the same object as the literal "Java".  If I then call s1.intern() I DO get the same object as the original literal.

"but the docs says that if the string does not exist it's created." -- Perhaps I'm missing something, but where in the quoted documentation does it say anything about intern() creating an object? All the documentation implies is "if string in pool, then return object from pool, else add string to pool and return string". No object is created in either case.

@Slaw - It depends on the implementation details of the string pool which are NOT specified by the javadoc.  In old implementations, intern() may create a new object ... in the PermGen heap.

@StephenC But from the point of view of Java (so to speak), which seems to me to be the context of the OP's question, no new String object is ever created. The documentation guarantees that for a string s not already in the pool, s.intern() == s will be true. Regardless of how the JVM handles the actual memory.

Well ... yea ... but the OP is asking in comments about what is happening under the hood; i.e. whether or not the string is copied.  See below.

@Haitam-Elgharras I suggest you [edit] your question to clarify if you're asking about implementation details or not. Or at least clarify what you find misleading about the documentation. Because to me at least, the documentation seems perfectly clear even if not all details (e.g., the under the hood memory management noted by Stephen C) regarding the pool are specified.

BTW after 20 years of using Java, I never had to use intern() or handle the pool of String - IMHO the only important point is that there is only one single instance of a literal. So using == to compare literals will work but fail with non-literals, that is, == should not be used (even if it worked in some [test] cases)

After carefully reading the answers and comments, I think I now understand exactly how String.intern() works. Let me explain with this code example:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating strings from bytes helps demonstrate that these strings 
    // are definitely NOT in the string pool initially
    String f1 = new String(new byte[] {0x68, 0x69});  // creates "hi" in heap only
    String f2 = new String(new byte[] {0x68, 0x69});  // creates another "hi" in heap only
    
    System.out.println("Equals: "+f1.equals(f2));  // true - same content
    
    
    String i1 = f1.intern();
    System.out.println("ref check for 1: "+(i1 == f1)); // true
    String i2 = f2.intern();
    System.out.println("ref check for 2: "+(i2 == f2)); // false
    System.out.println("ref check both: "+(i1 == i2)); // true
    
    // The crucial test:
    String str = "hi";  // String literals are always interned
    System.out.println("check f1 == hi: "+(f1 == str)); // true
}

What I learned:

When f1.intern() is called and "hi" isn't in the pool yet, what happens is: the actual String object referenced by f1 becomes the pooled instance. This is proven by the fact that i1 == f1 and "hi" == f1 return true - they're the exact same object.

When f2.intern() is called, since "hi" is already in the pool (it's f1's object), it returns that pooled instance. That's why:

i2 == f2 is false (different objects)
i1 == i2 is true (both point to the pooled instance)


The final test with String str = "hi" confirms this understanding. Since string literals are always interned, str must reference the pooled instance of "hi". The fact that f1 == str returns true proves that f1's object really did become the pooled instance.


This helped me understand what the documentation means by "this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned" - it's literally using the original string object as the pooled instance rather than creating a copy.
Using the byte array constructor (as shown in Progman's answer) made this especially clear because it guaranteed that the strings were initially only in the heap, not the pool, allowing us to see exactly what intern() does with the first and subsequent calls.


So when exactly does intern() actually add a new string to the pool?

Exactly1 when it needs to; i.e. when it wasn't already in the pool.
The call str.intern() has no knowledge of when or how the object referred to by str was created.  All the intern call knows is whether or not the object was already in the string pool.  (It checks!)  If it wasn't in the pool, it adds it.  Whether this involves creating a new string is an implementation detail.  See below.
Likewise, the specification of intern as set out in the javadocs don't make any reference to when or how the string was created, or how it works under the hood.  It is not relevant2.


Does intern() actually move the first string to the pool, or does it create a new copy?

It depends.

The javadoc doesn't specify which occurs.  It tells you that the result of the intern() call will be in the string pool.  Not how it happens.

In versions of Java prior to (I think) Java 7, the string pool lived in the PermGen heap.  In order to add a non-pooled string to the string pool, the intern() call needed to make a copy of the string in PermGen.

In current versions of Java, PermGen no longer exists and the string pool is (effectively) a data structure in the regular heap.  (It is behaves like a set of weakly referenced String objects.)  When a intern() call adds a non-pool string to the pool, it merely updates that data structure.  There is no need to create / copy a new String to do this.

In future versions of Java, this could change again without much warning, if there was a compelling reason to do so.



But frankly, your question is drilling down into details that a Java programmer simply doesn't need to know about.  Instead, you should follow these two simple rules.

Always use String::equals to compare strings.  Never use ==.
Avoid calling String::intern from application or library code.

If your application needs runtime string deduplication (i.e. to reduce heap space usage) it is more efficient to turn on GC string deduplication.  This deduplicates strings that live longer than a few new-space GC cycles.  Short-lived strings don't contribute to long-term space usage, and it is a waste of time for the GC to try to deduplicate them.  (Or for your application code to intern() them!)

1 - As @Slaw points out in the question comments, this is what the javadoc clearly says.  There is no ambiguity here.  Only possibly a misreading on your part.
2 - Including implementation details in the javadocs leads to people writing their code to depend on them.  That would be a bad thing, as it would limit the Java team's ability to ... in this case ... improve the performance of String.

Answer could be lightly improved perhaps to highlight how JVMs tend to work, which is: Any string literals from class files are interned; nothing else is. Which makes testing with e.g. String x = "foo"; String y = "foo".intern(); System.out.println(x == y); is a misleading way to try to figure out what's going on (on just about every JVM, that prints true), and concatenation similarly gets 'interned' due to the compiler figuring that out. (that tiny part of the answer is mentioned by Boann's answer; I upvoted both this and that answer as together they cover it all).

It could ... but that goes against the lesson that I am trying (hard) to teach the reader.  They simply don't need to know this stuff.


when we create a String using new, isn't the string literal already added to the String Pool?

The string literal in the source code (the thing in double quotes) is automatically interned.
But no new String is ever automatically interned.
This is easy to see:
System.out.println("Java" == new String("Java"));          // false
System.out.println("Java" == new String("Java").intern()); // true


When I actually test your code, I do not get the same object as the literal. String s1 = new String("Java"); does NOT return the same object as the literal "Java". If I then call s1.intern() I DO get the same object as the original literal.
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   System.out.println( Objects.toIdentityString( "Java" ) );
   String s = new String( "Java" );
   System.out.println( Objects.toIdentityString( s ) );
   s = s.intern();
   System.out.println( Objects.toIdentityString( s ) );
}

Output:
java.lang.String@63c12fb0
java.lang.String@b1a58a3
java.lang.String@63c12fb0


That's not what OP is asking. What OP is thinking (incorrectly) is that new String(anything) will necessarily add that string to the 'internal pool' unless, perhaps, it already exists. Therefore, .intern() would do nothing. The answer OP is looking for is 'no, the pool only contains stuff you explicitly intern() and any literals read straight from class files.

Hmm, well I think the code does answer the question.  The second line of output shows that new String() did not add anything to the pool.  And then the third line of output shows that that new string was then later added to the pool.  But maybe I'm still missing the point.

So this: What OP is thinking (incorrectly) is that new String(anything) will necessarily add that string to the 'internal pool' and the I said this: String s1 = new String("Java"); does NOT return the same object as the literal "Java" so I think I am saying and showing that the OP's thinking is incorrect, new String doesn't add anything to the intern pool.  Still thinking about how I might understand better...

I understand your confusion. That's because every peace of code in your class which is enclosed with either " or """ (called string literal and text block respectfully) are beeing added into String Pool during compile time. Whereas the keyword "new" doesn't add anything into String Pool instead it creates a reference to an object of type String and puts it somewhere into the memory heap during runtime. String literal "Java" and variable s1 point to different objects in heap memory so that's why you have to use String.intern when comparing them during runtime.
The only time when String.intern adds new string into the String Pool is when it doesn't already contain that exact string.
Source: java specification §3.10.5.

There are multiple constructors for the java.lang.String class, which do not involve a String literal. This means that the call
String s = new String(new byte[] {0x68, 0x69});

will not place the created string into the string pool, but s.intern() will (if there is no such string in the string pool yet). See the following example:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String f1 = new String(new byte[] {0x68, 0x69});
    System.out.println(f1);

    String f2 = new String(new byte[] {0x68, 0x69});
    System.out.println(f2);

    System.out.println("Equals: "+f1.equals(f2));

    String i1 = f1.intern();
    System.out.println("ref check for 1: "+(i1 == f1));
    String i2 = f2.intern();
    System.out.println("ref check for 2: "+(i2 == f2));
    System.out.println("ref check both: "+(i1 == i2));
}

This will generate the following output:
hi
hi
Equals: true
ref check for 1: true
ref check for 2: false
ref check both: true

As you see, the strings are equal to each other. The first intern() call will place the string into the string pool, the second intern() call will not. But since the original f1 string has been added to the string pool first, all other intern() calls will return the same instance (for the same string).

great explanation.
What I understand:
When f1.intern() is called and "hi" isn't in the pool, the original f1 object becomes the pool object
When f2.intern() is called and "hi" is already in the pool (from f1), f2 remains in heap while intern returns the pool reference
Is my understanding correct? Does intern() actually move the first string to the pool, or does it create a new copy?

It's difficult to answer because your question is kind of "if this but then this but also these".  Focusing the questions can help.  f2 remains on the heap until there are no reachable references to it.  Then at some time later the garbage collector removes it.  I know (I think) what you're asking, but it's important to keep that in mind.  intern() doesn't change the rules for reachable references or garbage collection.

@Haitam - intern() does not move anything; its pool just contains references to the instances (where ever this were created in) - it is NOT a replacement for the heap

look
ref check for 1: true
ref check for 2: false
i1 is a ref to the string pool and it's equal to f1 which is initially a separate object in the heap

But f2 has a reachable reference to the second string right up to the end of the program.  It's still on the heap because the code is holding a reference to it.
